# Is it possible to make spring mvc project as a Jar dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC to build our application, and we tried to use ajax for communicating with the server, we only render the basic pages by apache tiles.

And there a couple of modules, for example:

`app-data` will be responsible for some data uploading,processing and persisting. And the url mapping may looks like:

```
restful-like service:
    /api/data/excel (post,get,delete)
    /api/data/pdf (post,get,delete)

pages:
/data (home page for the data module, return a rendered html page)
```

`app-user` will be responsible for user managing, url mapping:

```
restful-like service:
    /api/user (post,get,delete,put)

pages:
/user (home page for the user module, return a rendered html page)
```

`app-site` will be responsible for the other pages like:

```
/about
/contact
/feedback
.....
```

BTW, we have another reason why we split them to different modules, some of the modules maybe re-used in other projects. We want all the pages and restful services re-used.

Now this is the application structure at the moment:

```
app
    app-data
        build.gradle
        src/main
            java
            resources

    app-user
        build.gradle
        src/main
            java
            resources
    app-site
        build.gradle
        src/main
            resources

            webapp
                static
                WEB-INF
                    jsps
                        header.jsp
                        footer.jsp
                        tiles
                            data.jsp
                            user.jsp
```

We expected the final application to be bundled with a war package contains the following content:

```
app
    static
    WEB-INF
        classes
            xx.properties
        lib
            app-data.jar (with resources including *.properties)
            app-user.jar (with resources including *.properties)
        jsps
            .....
```

And what's more, different modules may contains some different configurations by the *.properties, and we want to override some of them for example, once we have a new project, and we need the `user` feature, we copy the `app-site` and `app-user`, and override the properties in `/app-site/src/main/resources/*.properties`, then it is done.

I wonder if this is possbile?

Update:

---

I am not trying to make the `app-site` as as jar(thought it is possible with spring boot or something else), the `app-site` itself is still a war project, while its dependencies (`app-data` and `app-user`) are bundled as jars.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. If you create jar dependency project, how your WEB-INF and classes structure will be packaged will be still a question.  How about packaging jsps under resources folder of app-site and referring those jsps from any other web project as those jsps are available in the classpath? We have used this structure in the same way and worked for us.

Comment: The `app-data` and `app-user` does not contains jsps,.

Comment: If you wants spring mvc app in jar why don't you use springboot http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-spring-boot-web-application-project/ . If you cannot use springboot then you'll have to write custom logic to make it work. I have tried similar think with spring mvc for plugin framework (plugins packaged with class and static resources (js, css) in jar) if you want I can share the architecture with you.

Comment: why not deploy your rest-services `app-data` and `app-user` as war?

Comment: @RishiSaraf: I have updated my post, and also I am interested in your architecture,.

Comment: @s.ijpma: Non technological reasons :(.

Comment: Nope, you cannot do it. I have already tried it, asked a question also about this. My point was to use Apache Web server instead of Tomcat or any other application server, didn't fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily package controllers in different jars  which according to me is not problem in your case however issue will be with static contents like js, css and html. To serve them to browser you have to mark them mvc resource. Lets suppose you jar is follow below structure.

```
src
   main
       java (all controllers)
       resources
                webcontent 
                          css
                          js
                           app.js
```

As show above static content is in resources/webcontent folder. It can be served as mvc resource as below.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/webcontent/"/>
```

You can get app.js in your html as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```